# Why am getting two IP address

Tags: proxy, ip, internet

While using (http://www.whatsmyip.net/) I keep getting an IP6 in addition to my IP4.

Is it just me or this a general error with this site.

[image]

Comment: Because it detects an IPv6 address for you?  I'm not exactly sure what you're confused about.

Comment: You are asking a lot of basic networking questions here. This is not the place for them.

Comment: Maybe the Network Engineering SE would be a more appropriate place for this question?

Comment: Why do you think the IPv6 is an error?

Comment: @raz I flagged to go to [su]; AFAIK, Network Engineering is for more advanced networking questions.

Comment: @schroeder In this case it is an error. Because the `::ffff:0:0/96` is only used locally for sockets that are actually IPv4 on the wire. So the communication between client and server was entirely IPv4, yet the page told the user he had an IPv6 address which is misleading. If you visit the page from a host with an actual IPv6 address it looks different, and you will notice that the page design doesn't even have enough room for showing an IPv6 address in full, so it will appear truncated.

Comment: @kasperd I know that, but it was important for the OP to understand what was being asked.

Answer (score 4):

That IPv6 address is just an IPv6 version of your IPv4 address. Essentially, it's part of a block of IPv6 addresses reserved to represent IPv4 addresses so that applications running atop a stack which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 can just use a single address format, with the network stack taking care of sending out IPv4 packets or IPv6 packets depending on the address. Any IPv6 address in the range `::ffff:0:0/96` is an IPv6 representation of an IPv4 address.